# Write a list to file containing text and hex values. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a list of values to a text file. Because of Windows, when I need to write a line feed character, windows does \n\r and other systems do \n.

It occurred to me that maybe I should write to file in binary.

How to I create a list like the following example and write to file in binary?

```
output = ['my first line', hex_character_for_line_feed_here, 'my_second_line']
```

How come the following does not work?

```
output = ['my first line', '\x0a', 'my second line']
```

Comment: open the file in binary mode open(path,"wb")

Comment: i get that part for sure but in python 3.3, what does the hex representation of a line feed looks like using my example above? Something like... \x0a  ?

Comment: I guess my question is, how do I convert anything inside of a list to its hex character representation if it isn't already, then write to file?

Comment: `'\x0a'` is *exactly* the same character as `'\n'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Open the file in text mode and just let Python handle the newlines for you.

When you use the [`open()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) you can set how Python should handle newlines with the `newline` keyword parameter:

> When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

So the default method is to write the correct line separator for your platform:

```
with open(outputfilename, 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write('\n'.join(output))
```

and does the *right thing*; on Windows `\r\n` characters are saved instead of `\n`.

If you specifically want to write `\n` *only* and not have Python translate these for you, use `newline=''`:

```
with open(outputfilename, 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write('\n'.join(output))
```

Note that `'\x0a'` is *exactly* the same character as `\n`; `\r` is `\x0d`:

```
>>> '\x0a'
'\n'
>>> '\x0d'
'\r'
```

Comment: line feed is not the only hex character I'd like to add to this string. For some reason this does not work: output = ['my first line', '\x0a', 'my second line']

Comment: @Vini: Why do you need to add explicit linefeeds? They'll work just fine, btw, Python will write those to your file unchanged. `'\x0a'` *is the same character* as `\n`.

Comment: Record separators, Carriage Returns. I am basically building a string that follows a standard and gets encoded to pdf417 Bar Codes.

Comment: @Vini: If you need to write *exact* line separators, set `newline=''` and no translation takes place. If you need them translated to platform-specific newlines, use `newline=None`. This is still ASCII data, so textual mode is just fine.

Comment: @Martinjn Pieters: When I write in w mode '\x0a' and look at the text file in a hex editor a '\x0d' gets appended before '\x0a'. When I do it in wb mode, it crashes

Comment: @Vini: That is because you are opening the file with `newline=None` and a `\r\n` is written. Use `newline=''` instead.

Comment: Un... real. It's in the details after all. Thanks a lot Martinjn Pieters.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file, "myTextFile" in the same directory as your Python script. Then write something like:

```
# wb opens the file in "Write Binary" mode
myTextFile = open("myTextFile.txt", 'wb')

output = ['my first line', '369as3', 'my_second_line']

for member in output:
    member.encode("utf-8") # Or whatever encoding you like =)
    myTextFile.write(member + "\n")
```

This outputs a binary text file that looks like:

```
my first line
369as3
my_second_line
```

***Edit:** Updated for Python 3*

Comment: This is Python 3; you need to write *bytes*, not strings to files when opening a file in binary mode. Your code does not work on Python 3.

Comment: Ah I see, the OP didn't specify the version. Edited my code to encode the string to bytes first.

Comment: Yes, he did, in the tags on the question.

Comment: Didn't see the tag. Still, edited my code to encode the string to bytes first.